# Did Buddha forbid paying respect to deities of contemporary traditions?

Tags: the-buddha

Buddhism shares many deities with Brahmanism(Hinduism) and Jainism for example, Indra, Yama, etc. (Though the story associated with them might differ between the traditions, the central persona is the same).

There are also many other deities which Brahmanism and Jainism do not share with Buddhism. Did Buddha forbid paying respects to such deities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Buddhism shares many deities with Brahmanism(Hinduism) and Jainism for example, Indra, Yama, etc. (Though the story associated with them might differ between the traditions, the central persona is the same).

Buddhism does acknowledge existence of [deities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deity) but in a different context than Brahmanism / Hinduism. See: [God in Buddhism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_in_Buddhism), [Deva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deva_(Buddhism))

> There are also many other deities which Brahmanism and Jainism do not share with Buddhism. Did Buddha forbid paying respects to such deities?

There is not forbidding of paying respect to [deities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deity) or [Devas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deva_(Buddhism)). This can be used as a [subject of meditation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamma%E1%B9%AD%E1%B9%ADh%C4%81na).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I agree the context is different but the persona & core ideal are the same. As I had given example of Yama & Indra - they have different contexts but same core character.